# Why do i get Null Pointer Exception on MockMvc.perform?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc //need this in Spring Boot test
public class ApiControlerTest {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @MockBean
    private MockMvc mockMvc;  



    @Test
    public void writeWeightMetric() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mockMvc);
        String json = "{\"id\": \"15\", \"measurement\": 30, \"datetime\": \"29-12-2021-15-23-39\"}";

        mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("postURI")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

mockMvc is not null, but i get null pointer exception on line .andExpect...
Method I am calling returns JSON

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at ApiControlerTest.writeWeightMetric(ApiControlerTest.java:56) at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)